# how to hide the left: -100%

Tags: css, styled-components

i trying to implement nav bar that go from left to the screen.
**my problem:** when its go left the screen is stretched.
i want to not show this streched on the screen.

**note** that i cant use display:hidden, because i need some transition.

```
const NavBarUl = styled.ul`
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    width: ${p => (p.open ? "100%" : "0")};
    display: block;
    left: ${p => (p.open ? "0" : "-50%")};
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    flex-direction: column;
}
 `;
```

images for what happend:
[image: open nav]

[image: moved to here and i dont want]

[image: closed]

[image: after overflow hidden]

Comment: try changing width to max-width

Comment: doesnt work......

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop the page from expanding when animating an element so it slides in from off screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810481/how-do-i-stop-the-page-from-expanding-when-animating-an-element-so-it-slides-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use
`overflow-x:hidden` *(on the **body** f.ex.)*

Comment: wow thanks, i was needed to put it on the body, and no inside a parent div ... i dont understant why but.. thanks anyway.
btw, its gonna bother me later ? ...
I mean, can it interfere later in relatively normal designs?

Comment: it means you wont be able to scroll horizontally

Comment: No, in most cases it won't interfere. 
But I would still recommend you to use this on a wrapping element inside your HTML at a later stage, as you'll see that Safari Mobile will ignore this rule when it's placed on the body.

Comment: now i see when its responsive its going crazy out

Comment: Here would be an example with a container: https://jsfiddle.net/98pLmd0o/7/